# --packages behind proxy working in client mode but not cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a spark submit job on a gcloud dataproc cluster with one master node and two worker nodes. The spark job needs to resolve dependencies from a private password protected nexus repository. The spark cluster is also behind a corporate proxy.

The spark submit command I am using is:

```
spark-submit --verbose --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster/client --conf "spark.jars.ivySettings=./ivysettings.xml" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy port> -Drepo.username=<nexus username> -Drepo.password=<nexus password> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./truststore" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<proxy host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<proxy port> -Drepo.username=<nexus username> -Drepo.password=<nexus password> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./truststore" --files ./truststore,./ivysettings.xml --packages groupId:artifactId:version somejar.jar
```

The ivysettings.xml file is:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="nexus-resolver" />
    <credentials host="<host>" realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" username="${repo.username}" passwd="${repo.password}"/>
    <property name="repository-root" value="<nexus/repo/url>"/>
    <resolvers>
       <ibiblio name="nexus-resolver" m2compatible="true" root="${repository-root}"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

This successfully resolves dependencies and completes the job if I use client mode. However, in cluster mode spark hangs when trying to resolve dependencies.

```
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
```

And eventually times out with a server access error. From the proxy access logs I can see that no connection to proxy is made.

### Debugging

I can see spark is reading the extra java options passed to the executor by inspecting the debugging output.

I have tried sshing onto the worker nodes and running the same command from each one. Here I experience the same behavior (client mode works cluster mode does not). This rules out firewall settings on the worker nodes.

I have also tried setting the proxy at the environment level on all boxes. Same behavior.

It appears that --packages does not work in cluster mode when behind a proxy?

Comment: Hi. Did you ever got this problem solved ? I see the answer below, but I'm experiencing the same problem with proxies without authentication so the response doesn't apply for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely related to this issue about staging files in client vs cluster mode, since you rely on your `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` setting to point to a staged `--files` file. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-job-fails-in-cluster-mode/td-p/58772

You could try the fix described there, where you alias your staged files and then refer to the short filename in your java options:

```
--files ./truststore#truststore,./ivysettings.xml#ivysettings.xml ...
--conf "spark.jars.ivySettings=ivysettings.xml"  ...
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=truststore
```